# Custom CLinkPager Yii Framework

Tags: php, yii

basically:

```
<?php $this->widget('CLinkPager', array(
      'pages' => $pages,
)) ?>
```

when render: 'Go to page:...'
i want to push 'Go to page: ' to my element (ext: Go to page), somebody can help me?

Comment: you want to push means ?

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong you might want to access the **header** property of CLinker page which defaults to **Go to page**

```
<?php $this->widget('CLinkPager', array(
      'pages' => $pages,
      'header'=> 'whatever you want'
)) ?>
```